# Filesystem for boot partition

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, boot-loader

I created a BIOS boot partition on a hard drive, using gdisk :

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 7821312 sectors, 3.7 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F7F2BE49-B8D8-4910-8E69-381DEBD954DC
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 7821278
Partitions will be aligned on 4-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2 sectors (1024 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              36         7168035   3.4 GiB     EF02  BIOS boot partition
   2         7168036         7821278   319.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem

Command (? for help): q
```

I need to mount this BIOS partition :

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: block device /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

What is a relevant filesystem type to use in order to mount this BIOS partition? I read on the Internet that ext2 is fine, though I can't find an explanation why.

Answer (score 6):

A BIOS boot partition doesn't contain a filesystem; it's just a place to put some GRUB code that on an MBR disk would've been located immediately after the boot sector, before the start of the first partition.  On a GPT disk, that area is used by the (larger) partition table and isn't available for bootloader code, so the bootloader code goes in a small partition instead.

The BIOS boot partition should be very small:  a megabyte is more than enough.  Create a separate (larger) partition for your filesystem.

---

Note that some systems have a separate partition for the `/boot` directory, containing a filesystem with other files used by the bootloader.  *This is different from the BIOS boot partition.*

- The `/boot` directory contains the majority of the bootloader code and its configuration; this is what GRUB calls "stage 2".  Every Linux system needs these files.
- The BIOS boot partition is only applicable when you're using legacy MBR-style booting with a GPT disk.  It holds the "stage 1.5" code that the bootloader uses to mount the partition with the "stage 2" files.
- On a system that uses EFI-style booting, there's no BIOS boot partition.  Instead there's an EFI system partition that contains a completely different "stage 1" bootloader, which is able to mount `/boot` and access the "stage 2" files on its own, without needing "stage 1.5" as an intermediate step.

Comment: Yes. And the verifiable difference is code *`EF02`* in the output above. I think asker has pretty high hopes for `grub`'s abilities given the 3gb allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Wikipedia page on [BIOS boot partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) it looks as though it's really your choice.

*excerpt*

> The BIOS boot partition is typically quite small. It can be as small
>   as about 30 KiB; however, future boot loaders might require more
>   space, so creating a larger BIOS boot partition is advisable. Due to
>   the 1 MiB partition alignment, policies used by most modern disk
>   partitioning tools to provide optimum performance with Advanced Format
>   disks, SSD devices, and some types of RAID configurations, 1 MiB is a
>   logical size for a BIOS boot partition.

The list of tools that support it also doesn't look like it would cause any restrictions:

> The following utilities are known to support BIOS boot partitions:
>
> - GRUB 2 (1.97~beta1 or later): when a BIOS boot partition is found during installation, GRUB will embed itself in it.
> - GNU Parted (2.0 or later).
> - GParted, the front-end to GNU Parted.
> - gpt(8) partition editor in NetBSD (5.0 or later).
> - gdisk: GPT fdisk

So I would probably use either ext2 or ext3, with a slight leaning towards ext3.

Comment: There is no need for journal for boot FS, imo. ext2 is a right choice.